# How to assign variable fig for animation function in Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-animation, yt

I want to make an animation of multiple plots whose rendering evolves in time.

The files that I need are under the format, for example for one :

`DD0043/DD0043`. So I use the trick : `f'{43:04}'` to fill the zeros leading for each file (the files go from `DD0000/DD0000` to `DD0922/DD0922`.

Here the script, warning, the plot is done with `yt-project` tool :

```
import yt
import os, sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc_context
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(i):
  plot._switch_ds(array_data[i])

# Number of files
numFiles = int(os.popen('ls -dl DD* | wc -l').read())

# Array for each data directory
array_data = np.array(numFiles)

for i in range(numFiles):
  data = yt.load('DD'+str(f'{i:04}')+'/DD'+str(f'{i:04}'))
  sc = yt.create_scene(data, lens_type='perspective')

  source = sc[0]

  source.set_field('density')
  source.set_log(True)

  # Set up the camera parameters: focus, width, resolution, and image orientation
  sc.camera.focus = ds.domain_center
  sc.camera.resolution = 1024
  sc.camera.north_vector = [0, 0, 1]
  sc.camera.position = [1.7, 1.7, 1.7]

  # You may need to adjust the alpha values to get an image with good contrast.
  # For the annotate_domain call, the fourth value in the color tuple is the
  # alpha value.
  sc.annotate_axes(alpha=.02)
  sc.annotate_domain(ds, color=[1, 1, 1, .01])

  text_string = "T = {} Gyr".format(float(array_data[i].current_time.to('Gyr')))

fig = plt.figure()
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=numFiles)

# Override matplotlib's defaults to get a nicer looking font
with rc_context({'mathtext.fontset': 'stix'}):
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
```

But at the execution, I get the following error :

```
923
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vol-annotated.py", line 52, in <module>
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1135, in save
    anim._init_draw()
  File "/Users/fab/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1743, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
StopIteration
```

I don't know if I do the things correctly, especially for the variable `fig` that I initialize with :

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

Actually, I am trying to adapt to my case this script which creates a movie :

[make animation](https://yt-project.org/doc/cookbook/complex_plots.html#time-series-movie)

i.e :

```
import yt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc_context

ts = yt.load('GasSloshingLowRes/sloshing_low_res_hdf5_plt_cnt_*')

plot = yt.SlicePlot(ts[0], 'z', 'density')
plot.set_zlim('density', 8e-29, 3e-26)

fig = plot.plots['density'].figure

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(i):
    ds = ts[i]
    plot._switch_ds(ds)

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(ts))

# Override matplotlib's defaults to get a nicer looking font
with rc_context({'mathtext.fontset': 'stix'}):
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
```

**UPDATE 1:** I didn't find a way to use `animation.save` correctly to generate an animation: always this issue about the `fig` variable.

But I managed to generate all the images corresponding for each one to an output file `DDxxxx/DDxxxx`. I have proceeded like this:

```
import yt
import os, sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc_context

# Number of files
numFiles = int(os.popen('ls -dl DD* | wc -l').read())

# Loop to load input files
ts = []
for j in range(numFiles):
  ts = np.append(ts, yt.load('DD'+str(f'{j:04}')+'/DD'+str(f'{j:04}')))

plot = yt.SlicePlot(ts[0], 'z', 'density')
plot.set_zlim('density', 8e-29, 3e-26)

# create plotting figure
fig = plot.plots['density'].figure

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(i):
  ds = ts[i]
  sc = yt.create_scene(ds, lens_type='perspective')

  source = sc[0]

  source.set_field('density')
  source.set_log(True)

  # Set up the camera parameters: focus, width, resolution, and image orientation
  sc.camera.focus = ds.domain_center
  sc.camera.resolution = 1024
  sc.camera.north_vector = [0, 0, 1]
  sc.camera.position = [1.7, 1.7, 1.7]

  # You may need to adjust the alpha values to get an image with good contrast.
  # For the annotate_domain call, the fourth value in the color tuple is the
  # alpha value.
  sc.annotate_axes(alpha=.02)
  sc.annotate_domain(ds, color=[1, 1, 1, .01])

  text_string = "T = {} Gyr".format(float(ds.current_time.to('Gyr')))

  ## Here the scene needs to be painted into my figure / plot. 
  sc.save('rendering_'+str(i)+'.png')

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=numFiles)

# Override matplotlib's defaults to get a nicer looking font
with rc_context({'mathtext.fontset': 'stix'}):
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
```

If I open a single `.png`, I get a correct image representing a 3D scene.

Unfortunately, the animation function is not working, I get just a 2D heatmap plot showing the density projected: I would like to get an animation of the 3D scene figures (`rendering_xxx.png`).

It seems that I have to use `ffmpeg` to generate this animation from the multiple `.png` image, excepted if I find a way to know how to use Python `FuncAnimation` function (included in `yt` library ? or in Python by default ?).

**UPDATE 2:** here an example of figure (a frame actually) of animation I would like to get (this is a figure which represents gas density inside a box, i.e. in 3D) :

[image: figure representing a 3D scene]

Unfortunately, @NightTrain's script produces this kind of plot :

[image: NightTrain's result : 2D heatmap figure]

As you can see, I don't understand why I get a 2D heatmap with NightTrain's solution instead of a 3D scene.

Moreover, there is no animation in this 2D heatmap, the movie displays always this same figure.

**UPDATE3 :** the last solution suggested by @Night train produces the following error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "plot_3D_enzo_with_animation_LAST.py", line 30, in <module>
        plot = yt.SlicePlot(ts[0], 'z', 'density')
      File "/Users/henry/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/yt/data_objects/time_series.py", line 201, in __getitem__
        o = self._pre_outputs[key]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why this error occurs.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: `yt` offers volume rendering but that has to be done within `yt` you can either save an image with `sc.save()` or you can return just the array with `sc.render()`. The latter can be passed on and later saved as a video. Therefore openCV or imageio might be a good choice.

Comment: Do you need to use matplotlib, or would your setting also allow for using another library like imageio?

Comment: Since the list index is out of range it looks like he has problems accessing the files. Can you check if the files have been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could provide more information it would be easier to help. I fixed your code and it is running now.
You also forgot to use the `text_string` variable.
Since the `array_data` variable isn't used I removed it.

```py
import yt
import os, sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc_context
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import pathlib
import glob

base_path = "enzo_tiny_cosmology"
paths = sorted(glob.glob(base_path + "/DD*/DD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"))
# paths = [x.joinpath(x.name).as_posix() for x in sorted(pathlib.Path(base_path).glob("DD*"))]

# Array for each data directory
# array_data = np.zeros(len(paths))
# array_data = [None for x in range(len(paths))]

ts = yt.load(paths)
# ts = yt.load(base_path + "/DD*/DD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
# print(ts.outputs)

plot = yt.SlicePlot(ts[0], 'z', 'density')
fig = plot.plots['density'].figure

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(i):

  data = ts[i]
  sc = yt.create_scene(data, lens_type='perspective')

  source = sc[0]

  source.set_field('density')
  source.set_log(True)

  # Set up the camera parameters: focus, width, resolution, and image orientation
  sc.camera.focus = data.domain_center
  sc.camera.resolution = 1024
  sc.camera.north_vector = [0, 0, 1]
  sc.camera.position = [1.7, 1.7, 1.7]

  # You may need to adjust the alpha values to get an image with good contrast.
  # For the annotate_domain call, the fourth value in the color tuple is the
  # alpha value.
  sc.annotate_axes(alpha=.02)
  sc.annotate_domain(data, color=[1, 1, 1, .01])

  text_string = "T = {} Gyr".format(float(data.current_time.to('Gyr')))

  plot._switch_ds(data)

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(paths))

# Override matplotlib's defaults to get a nicer looking font
with rc_context({'mathtext.fontset': 'stix'}):
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
```

Instead of counting the lines of `ls -dl`you might want to use a python solution. which also lets you use the paths directly without contructing them later. You can use either pathlib or the os module.

```py
import pathlib
import glob

base_path = "enzo_tiny_cosmology"
paths = sorted(glob.glob(base_path + "/DD*/DD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"))
paths = [x.joinpath(x.name).as_posix() for x in sorted(pathlib.Path(base_path).glob("DD*"))]
```

For testing I downloaded these datasets:

```sh
curl -sSO https://yt-project.org/data/enzo_tiny_cosmology.tar.gz
tar xzf enzo_tiny_cosmology.tar.gz

curl -sSO https://yt-project.org/data/GasSloshingLowRes.tar.gz
tar xzf GasSloshingLowRes.tar.gz
```

UPDATE:

If you want to save the rendered scenes as video you could e.g. use `imageio` or `opencv`:

```py
import yt, glob, imageio

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(data):
  sc = yt.create_scene(data, lens_type='perspective')

  source = sc[0]
  source.set_field('density')
  source.set_log(True)

  # Set up the camera parameters: focus, width, resolution, and image orientation
  sc.camera.focus = data.domain_center
  sc.camera.resolution = 1024
  sc.camera.north_vector = [0, 0, 1]
  sc.camera.position = [1.7, 1.7, 1.7]

  # You may need to adjust the alpha values to get an image with good contrast.
  # For the annotate_domain call, the fourth value in the color tuple is the
  # alpha value.
  sc.annotate_axes(alpha=.02)
  sc.annotate_domain(data, color=[1, 1, 1, .01])

  plot._switch_ds(data)
  sc.save(f'rendering_{i:04d}.png')
  return sc.render()

paths = sorted(glob.glob("/DD*/DD[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"))
ts = yt.load(paths)
plot = yt.SlicePlot(ts[0], 'z', 'density')
plot.set_zlim('density', 8e-29, 3e-26)

vid_writer = imageio.get_writer("animation.mp4", fps = 10)
for frame in ts:
    rendered_image = animate(frame)
    vid_writer.append_data(rendered_image)
vid_writer.close()
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! I am going to test this. What's the utility of the second data set `GasSloshingLowRes.tar.gz` ? I don't see it in your script.

Comment: I have just tested it and the movie is not the expected result, at least from the 3D scene animated that I would like to get. With your script, I have yet a 2D heatmap and not a 3D scene. I add examples of figure expected in **UPDATE2**

Comment: What do you mean by "utility"?

Comment: I ran the code with the data I downloaded from yt-project and the video was similar to the one of the code you've linked to. you could of course render a time series as a 3D model. But is that what you want to do? The examples you've provided are not for that purpose.

Comment: I just added a code to save a video of the 3D scenes. Is that what you were aiming for? It also shows the bounding box.

Comment: I just saw the video differs from the images for some reason. I'm not sure if there is a possibility to get the images as arrays, but most likely it will be the easiest to write out the images and then merge them to a video with either ffmpeg or with imageio, just as you suggested.

Comment: I have added the error generated by your script into **UPDATE3** : it seems not possible to iterate over enzo data output files. Have you got a trick to circumvent this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that I can see right away.

1. The animate function refers to a `plot` variable that is not defined.
2. `array_data = np.array(numFiles)` will result in the number of files in a one-item numpy array. Probably not intended and will cause that `array_data[i]` fails for `i>=1`.
3. `array_data` is not filled with data afterwards, either.
4. I don't see any plotting being done. `fig = plt.figure()` will only provide you with an empty figure.

So, with that I'll restructure your code a bit:

```
import yt
import os, sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import rc_context
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Number of files
numFiles = int(os.popen('ls -dl DD* | wc -l').read())

# create plotting figure
fig = plt.figure()

# animate must accept an integer frame number. We use the frame number
# to identify which dataset in the time series we want to load
def animate(i):
  data = yt.load('DD'+str(f'{i:04}')+'/DD'+str(f'{i:04}'))
  sc = yt.create_scene(data, lens_type='perspective')

  source = sc[0]

  source.set_field('density')
  source.set_log(True)

  # Set up the camera parameters: focus, width, resolution, and image orientation
  sc.camera.focus = ds.domain_center
  sc.camera.resolution = 1024
  sc.camera.north_vector = [0, 0, 1]
  sc.camera.position = [1.7, 1.7, 1.7]

  # You may need to adjust the alpha values to get an image with good contrast.
  # For the annotate_domain call, the fourth value in the color tuple is the
  # alpha value.
  sc.annotate_axes(alpha=.02)
  sc.annotate_domain(ds, color=[1, 1, 1, .01])

  text_string = "T = {} Gyr".format(float(data.current_time.to('Gyr')))

  ## Here the scene needs to be painted into your figure / plot. 


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=numFiles)

# Override matplotlib's defaults to get a nicer looking font
with rc_context({'mathtext.fontset': 'stix'}):
    animation.save('animation.mp4')
```

However, I also see in the example that yt supports loading several files at once: 
`ts = yt.load('GasSloshingLowRes/sloshing_low_res_hdf5_plt_cnt_*')` so you might want to consider that as well.

I'm well aware that this is not a running example, but I hope this will help you tracking this down.